# X-axis plotting in the wrong place

Tags: string, list, matplotlib, plot

all. I'm trying to make a plot, whereby the data for x-axis is in a list of dates all written as strings in the format "yyyy-mm-dd". Now I'm trying to plot for dates that are all in November. On the 18th of November a change was made and so I've draw a line on the plot for the date and I'm trying to compare data that should be on either side of the line. The problem is that the data points for the 18th of November, along with the line, seem to appear at either the beginning of x-axis for some plots, and at the end of the x-axis for other plots, without any rhyme or reason, as far as I can tell, even though the 18th of November is supposed to show up in the middle of the month.

What's confusing me even further is that I've done these plots before with data going from October to December, and for the most part the plots come out fine. All I've changed since is only plotting dates from November, could anyone possible know what might cause this?

To be honest, I've been struggling to come up with theories as to why this could be happening, so I have no idea how to even test what could be the cause of the problem.

Here is my code, sorry that it's so long, but I figured I should give a holistic context:

```
1mon = "-11-"
for j in range(len(badDestinations)):
        
        BDestination = badDestinations[j]["destination"]
        Time = badDestinations[j]["time"]
        
7       year, month, date = day.partition(mon)
        
9       if month == mon:
        
            if BDestination == "Burns":
                Burns.append(Time)
                Burnsday.append(day)
           
            
        for k in range(len(goodDestinations)):
            
            GDestination = goodDestinations[k]["destination"]
            Time = goodDestinations[k]["time"]
            
21          year, month, date = day.partition(mon)
            
23          if month == mon:
                
                if GDestination == "Burns":
                    Burns.append(Time)
                    Burnsday.append(day)
                
            
Burns.reverse()
Burnsday.reverse()

from matplotlib.pyplot import plot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, xlabel, ylabel, title
%matplotlib qt5

#Burns graph
figure(1)
title('Burns Unit Wait times')
plt(Burnsday,Burns)
plt(["2022-11-18","2022-11-18"],[0,max(Burns)], 'r--')
xlabel('Day')
ylabel('Waiting time')
```

The only thing that I've changed from the .py file analyzing data from October-December to the one only analyzing November are adding in lines 1, 7, 9, 21, and 23, (I've written the numbers of these lines at the beginning of each respective line) along with the indentations that would be required for the loops associated with those lines.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, try to reduce your question to a minimum small example that reproduces your problem. If one figure is enough to reproduce the problem, then don't show more, they will only make it more difficult to get an answer from SO.

Comment: Btw, you may want to search the web about "if elif".

Comment: Thank you. Will try reduce the information, and have a look at "if elif".